# create nested parallel stages in a loop Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have list of items, each of them need to go through two stages, when for each of the items the stages must to be one after the other,
but the items can run parallelly.
So, I tried to create a nested parallel stages for every item in the list, so all the items will run parallelly, and for each of them the stages will run one after the other
when I tried to do it without a loop (only for 2 items from my list) it worked this way:

```
stage('nested parallel stage') {
    parallel {
        stage("stages for item1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    stage("stage1 for item1 ") {
                        sh "echo stage 1 for item1"
                    } //stage 1
                    stage("stage 2 for item1") {
                        sh "echo stage 2 to item1"
                    } // stage 2
                } //script
            } // steps
        } // stage
        stage("stages for item2") {
            steps {
                script {
                    stage("staqge1 for item 2") {
                        sh "echo stage 1 for item2"
                    } //stage 1
                    stage("stage 2 for item2") {
                        sh "echo stage 2 to item2"
                    } // stage2
                } //script
            } // steps
        } // stage
    } //parallel
} // nested parallel stage
```

It worked without any problem.
But, when I tried to do it in a loop, like this:

```
def itemsMap = getitemsMap ()
def parallelItemsStages = itemsMap.collectEntries{
    [ "${it.value.item}": {
            stage("stages for ${it.value.item}") {
                steps{
                    script {
                        stage("stage 1 for ${it.value.item}") {
                            sh "echo stage 1 for ${it.value.item}"
                        } //stage 1
                        stage("stage 2 for ${it.value.item}") {
                            sh "echo stage 2 for ${it.value.item}"
                        } // stage 2
                    } // script
                } // steps
            } // stage
        } // nested stages
    }] // collectEntries
} // collectEntries
parallel parallelItemsStages
```

I got this error:

```
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps
```

Comment: Your syntax looks a little bit off. Shouldn't `itemsMap.collectEntries` be followed by an open parentheses? Also, the error doesn't make sense since you haven't declared the `steps` block anywhere.

Comment: Where previously you've had `stage { steps {` now you have `stage { stages {`. Maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: My bad.. it was ```stage { steps {``` and then I changed it to ```stage { stages {``` but I got the same error.. Also, as far as I know, there is no need of parentheses for the ```itemsMap.collectEntries```, but I added and got the same results

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand getitemsMap (); May I ask what is the role of ***def itemsMap = getitemsMap ()***

Comment: This map contains some metadata of my items s, and this is who I did a parallel loop over my items and generated stages, but It worked only for one stage per item.

Comment: Hi @yiaca sorry for the tardiness, Hope you have resolved your issue, in case if you have not,  I tried executing the script at my end, and found the following error _java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'getitemsMap' found among steps_.  I'm believe I need additional data here, from looking at the error, I would recommend try something like below

Comment: enclosing sh statement in steps that is expected ```stage("stage 1 for ${it.value.item}") {
        steps {
            sh "echo stage 1 for ${it.value.item}"
     } //steps at stage 1
 } //stage 1```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def itemsMap = getitemsMap ()
def parallelItemsStages = itemsMap.collectEntries{
    [ "${it.value.item}": {
            script {
                stage("stage 1 for ${it.value.item}") {
                    sh "echo stage 1 for ${it.value.item}"
                } //stage 1
                stage("stage 2 for ${it.value.item}") {
                    sh "echo stage 2 for ${it.value.item}"
                } // stage 2
            } // script
        } // nested stages
    }] // collectEntries
} // collectEntries
parallel parallelItemsStages
```

that worked for me just now :)